# Selenium Grid Hub and Nodes Issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-grid

HELPPPP PLEASSEE!

Now that i've made my setup of selenium grid with the following:

-Machine A with a hub and node on it (node in the same machine of the hub).
-Machine B (different machine than the hub not the same), with 2 nodes on it.

Therefore i have now a hub and 3 nodes : 1 on the hub machine(Machine A) acting as a node also, and 2 on the other physical node machine(Machine B).

so with this setup i can run 3 test cases in parallel AFAIK.

I would help with everything i did.

**The setup command for the hub:**

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role hub -port 4445

(i changed the port number from the default one)

**The setup command for the node:**

> java -jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\Libraries\IEDriverServer.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\Libraries\chromedriver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role webdriver -hub http://HubIP:4445/grid/register -port 4453

Then comes the code in C# for the setup and the tests:

```
     using System;
     using OpenQA.Selenium;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Safari;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
     using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
     using NUnit;
     using NUnit.Framework;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using System.Threading;
     using System.Threading.Tasks;


    namespace GridTest
         {
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class Grid_Test
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {


            ///Chrome setup///
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
          capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
          capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", false);
          capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Any));
          driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.10.17.223:4445/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        }



        [Test]

        [Parallelizable]
        public void SeleniumSearch()
        {
            //var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.seleniumhq.org/");

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {

            driver.Quit();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class Test_Grid2
    {
        IWebDriver driver2;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

            ///Chrome setup///
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
           capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
           capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
           capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", false);
           capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Any));
           driver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.10.17.223:4445/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        }


        [Test]
        [Parallelizable]
        public void BingSearch()
        {
            //var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver2.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com");

        }


        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            driver2.Quit();
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class Test_Grid3
    {
        IWebDriver driver3;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {



            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
            capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", false);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Any));
            driver3 = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.10.17.223:4445/wd/hub"), capabilities);


        }


        [Test]
        [Parallelizable]
        public void SeleniumSearch()
        {
            //var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver3.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.seleniumhq.org/");

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            driver3.Quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**I have 2 main problems now:**

1)when i run the tests, it should run the 3 tests in parallel, this doesn't happen only 2 tests run at the same time and i don't know why.

2) The tests don't run on chrome browsers, it just opens up the page and the tests don't continue. the error in the command says:
Chrome failed to start: crashed.

Any idea what are the problems coming from ??

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
-The second problem is solved by uninstalling and installing chrome again. didn't know what was the problem with the older browser.

**EDIT2**
- Solved the first problem ALSO, i know that grid's community is very poor here as well as the Nunit, the problem for running 2 tests only was because of the default value of **LevelOfParallelism** attribute 
so to increase the number of tests to run in parallel write this in the assemblyInfo.cs file 
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(X)]
where X the number of parallel threads that could run.

> Is running multiple tests related to the number of cores of the hub
>   ONLY ?? cause if so my hub is only 2 cores so maybe this would be the
>   case. but this makes a very limited restriction that the hub must have
>   a lot of cores. i want to ask since the node can have by default 11
>   instances(5 chrome,5 FF, 1 IE), would it be able to run 11 test cases
>   in parallel on those instances ??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The **second problem** is solved by uninstalling and installing chrome  again. didn't know what was the problem with the older browser.
- Solved the **first problem** ALSO, i know that grid's community is very poor here as well as the Nunit, the problem for running 2 tests only was because of the default value of LevelOfParallelism attribute so to increase the number of tests to run in parallel write this in the assemblyInfo.cs file **[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(X)]** where X the number of parallel threads that could run.